How do I update a column based on a match to 2nd table using another column from my target table?
This is a postgresql DB.  I have users in my users table that are associated with a customer entity by a customer_id column.  The customer is broken down into smaller segments by department and the users are assigned to a department.  It looks something like this.
Customer Table



id
name
external_id
etc...




1111
Cust 1
aaaa



2222
Cust 2
bbbb



3333
Cust 3
cccc




Department Table



id
name
customer_id
etc...




aaaa
Cust 1
4444



bbbb
Cust 2
4444



cccc
Cust 3
4444




User Table



id
department_id
customer_id
etc...




1234
aaaa
4444



5678
bbbb
4444



9012
cccc
4444




I want to create new customer records for each department and migrate the users to the correct new customer record based on their current department affiliation.  I have already created the new customer records and tracked their previous department_id in the external_id field just so I have that for reference.
I now need to update each user's customer_id to map them to the correct new customer record.  I tried to match the user's current department_id to the corresponding external_id in the customer table using the SQL below, but that didn't work.  It didn't throw an error, but also didn't make the change I needed.
UPDATE users u
  SET customer_id = c.id
  FROM customers c
  WHERE CAST(u.department_id AS VARCHAR) = c.external_id
    AND c.id = 242;

Anyone have a strategy that would help me avoid dozens of manual queries to update these records?

Please update the post with each table's DDL, including indexes and constraints. Provide sample data as executable statements to populate those tables and the expected table contents after the updates. A [mre] makes it much easier for the SO community to provide useful assistance.
